# Trying to get Magento to Resize product images.

Tags: css, image, magento, resize, themes

My site is http://www.acuity-sports.com/

I'm trying to get the product images to resize.   Not sure what css file needs to be tinkered with to accomplish this.

My "Theme" tells me to do this. "Width is a required field. If only width is specified, the image will be re-sized proportionally. If both width and height are specified, the image will be re-sized exactly. You will need to update your custom CSS in order to have the resized images displayed correctly in your store."

http://www.acuity-sports.com/volleyball/3mm-professional-olympic-volleyball-net-32-x-3-official.html

It's a little confusing to me.   Any advice on the code I need to find or use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to resize product image then you can do that by code no need to update css.

for resize image of product list page go to yourtheme\template\catalog\product\list.phtml
and for product detail page go yourtheme\template\catalog\product\view\media.phtml
and use resize function.

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks!   Been looking for a fix like this!